# my .htaccess not working on apache for redirect to parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have the following url type http://example.com/?i=home and I am trying to get `http://example.com/home`. I'm getting 404 error message. I have tried to restart apache2 and tried to work with the .htaccess file. Any help will appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?i=$1 [L]
```

Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That didn't work. I am using apache2, ubuntu 64bit> i did restart apache2. Still getting 404.

Comment: I checked and edited my post. Please, try this ! I tested this, worked here !

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule /(.*?)$ /?i=$1 [L]`

Double check that mod_rewrite is enabled at /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ & look for possible msg at apache error log (/var/log/apache2)

Comment: My Apache Error is blank. My access log shows 404 but not why. It shows [30/Sep/2014:12:16:25 -0400] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"

Comment: did you check that mod_rewrite is enabled? it appears that rewrite is not working or .htaccess is not accesible to apache, check that www-data is owner/group and 644 recommended permission is set.